# How to use flex with lists in html?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was trying to create my portfolio page. I have 4 subheadings (About, Resume, Blog and Portfolio).

So I wanted to put these headings on top center of my div. So what I did was created an unordered list gave it property to display inline. Now all headings come to the same list.

Now I want to give spacing between the headings. Of course margin and padding options are there but is there any way in which I can avoid margin/paddings and do this directly by flex?(I wanted to reduce load on media queries for small screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul` can be the flex container, and you can spread the elements evenly using `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header">
  <li class="header__item">About</li>
  <li class="header__item">Resume</li>
  <li class="header__item">Blog</li>
  <li class="header__item">Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can u share the css for header__item also?

Comment: ok i got it, i forgot to give width, added some width to it, now works fine.

Comment: There isn't any styling for `header__item`, just added it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Missed the 'center' it in your question. Yep - added `width`. Remove the `padding` of the `ul`, and use `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

Answer (score 0):

you may use justify-content and eventually pseudo elements to squeeze elements to middle

```css
nav {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
/*increase space from side at first and last child */
nav:before,
nav:after {
  content:'';
  width:25vw;/* or % . tune this or remove pseudo if unneeded */
}
a {
  margin:0 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Resume</a>
  <a href="#">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Folio</a>
</nav>
```